# Cordova Plugin Performance Limitations - Hybrid vs Native

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins

Are there performance limitations in plugin creation for a Cordova project?

*If I need specific native functionality, can I not create ANY plugin to provide this functionality and pop back into the web-view following utilizing this native functionality?* Say a plugin with advanced camera functionality on a timer w/ geotagging.

I may need to learn more about plugin development in order to answer this question myself. Perhaps someone has the answer.

I've been learning Cordova and Hybrid dev for the last year and now learning native Android. Alternatively, it seems a **[Native Hybrid/Embedded Web View](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/webviews/index.html)** app could give you the best of both worlds? Potentially mixing both Native and Hybrid UI?

Thanks SO community!